# Custom method in single repositories returns null

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I followed the reference guide for creating and customizing Repositories and came up with the following:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, UserRepositoryCustom {
}


@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserRepositoryCustomImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {

    @Override
    public User findByToken(UUID token) {
          return new User();
    }
}


public interface UserRepositoryCustom {
    User findByToken(UUID token);
}
```

In my case `userRepository.findByToken(token);`returns null.

@Edit

The test below fails

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = NONE)
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{
        assertNotNull(userRepository.findByToken(UUID.randomUUID()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share additional code as well, like where you have autowired userRepository, User model etc.

Comment: @midryuk did autowired the userRepository

Comment: @Akash yes, I autowired the userRepository

Comment: Your diagnostic is most probably wrong. Post the code, and its output, that makes you think the method returns null.

Comment: What's the output of the test execution? My guess is that it fails because it can't load the application context (not because the result is null). And it can't load the context because the class should be named UserRepositoryImpl, not UserRepositoryCustomImpl.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom implementation is named wrong. It should be named after the class name of the Repository, not after the interface declaring the custom method.

Just renamed `UserRepositoryCustomImpl` to `UserRepositoryImpl`

The reason the method currently returns `null` is because Spring Data creates a query from the name and doesn't find a `User` with the specified token.